# Select more than one Element jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to select more than one element in the same page.

For example, this:

```
$("#administratorUsername").mouseenter(function () {
      $("#administratorUsername").focus();
});

$("#administratorPassword").mouseenter(function () {
      $("#administratorPassword").focus();
});
```

Also I need to select the `label` element to apply the same code.

Ex: `$("#administratorUsername, label")`, `$("#administratorUsername - label")`.

I don't know how to do it, and this is precisely my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$('#administratorUserName, #administratorPassword').mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).focus();
});
```

That should work. Note the comma in between. You also have to switch to using the object that was selected. Hence the change to `$(this).focus()` as opposed to specifically selecting again.

Comment: @user2465422 - Happy to help. If you could accept my answer so others know that this answered your question (click the checkmark under the vote buttons), I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

Like this

```
    $("#administratorUsername,#administratorPassword").mouseenter(function () {
      $(this).focus();  //current element.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read [JQuery multiple-selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

It works with a , seperation.

```
$("#first, #second, #third").mouseenter( function() {
  $(this).focus()
});
```

Also check the docs for the  .on method.